# What is the opposite of "down-home cooking"?

Tags: meaning, vocabulary, antonyms

What is the opposite of *down-home cooking*? Somehow *uptown gastronomy* doesn’t sound right.

Comment: What is the opposite of an apple? Not everything has to have an antonym.

Comment: If you don't have an apple, you get a doctor.

Comment: *Fancy-schmancy*?

Comment: @phenry - A PC of course.

Comment: @phenry orange.

Comment: **Not all words have opposites.** Furthermore it is **a common mistake by questioners on ELU to ask for opposites inappropriately**.

Answer (score 10):

Per Wikipedia:

> *[Haute cuisine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gourmet)*: Gourmet is a cultural ideal associated with the culinary arts of fine food and drink, or haute cuisine, which is characterised by refined, even elaborate preparations and presentations of aesthetically balanced meals of several contrasting, often quite rich courses

Comment: Notice that _haute_ means 'high', so that's vertically opposed to down-home. Also it's worldwide, while downhome is local.

Answer (score 3):

How about *fast food*? Much of it is pre-processed, heat and serve, about as far from cooking as you can get.  The words are not opposite, but the meaning is.

Answer (score 3):

Going in another direction here: *processed food*.